# Tensorflow 2.0 sobel_edges image format?

Tags: image-processing, sobel, tensorflow2.x

I'm trying to get tf.image.sobel_edges to work in tensorflow 2.2.0, but it seems like even the simplest example doesn't work:

```
    img_path = "./test.jpg"
    image = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    sobel = tf.image.sobel_edges(img)
```

results in **tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: The first dimension of paddings must be the rank of inputs[4,2], [224,224,3] [Op:MirrorPad]**

[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fs8Z.png)

I was thinking that this might have something to do with Channel ordering and the function is looking for an alpha channel, but I can't figure what the 2 is. Has anyone used this with tf-2?